# flutter post request with header and body

Tags: flutter

anyone could help me to write flutter request post for the following header and body with the corresponding response below;

Example Post Request

## Header Request:

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

## Body Request:

```
grant_type: client_credentials

scope: accounts

client_assertion_type: code**

client_assertion: code**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following,

```
String hostname = "myhostname";// example
String port = "1234"; //example
String url = "https://$hostname:$port/as/token.oauth2";
String body = "{'grant_type' : '$client_credentials' }" +
              "'scope' : '$accounts'" +
              //... etc etc 
              "'Corresponding Response': { 'access_token': 'JWt CODE', 'expires_in': '86400', 'token_type': 'bearer', 'scope': 'payments' }"+
             "}";
var res = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url),
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: body);
```

Comment: error: I/flutter (15151): "{\"timestamp\":\"2019-08-11T21:55:18.737+0000\",\"status\":400,\"error\":\"Bad Request\",\"message\":\"Required String parameter 'grant_type' is not present\",\"path\":\"/as/token.oauth2\"}"

Comment: `"Required String parameter 'grant_type' is not present"` is your grant_type client_credentials null?

Comment: this is the code im using currently; `code` Future<String> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      body: jsonEncode(
        {'grant_types': 'accounts'} +
            {'scope': 'client_credentials'} +
            {'client_assertion_type': 'urn%3Aiearer'} +
            {'client_assertion': 'eyJVwTTeh4BXg'},
      ),
    );
    print(jsonDecode(response.body));
    return getData();
  } `code`

Comment: Looks like you have a typo `'grant_types' 'grant_type'`

Comment: Yes maybe when i cope and past it was one try. But even with the correct payload im still recieving 400

Comment: Are you able to make a working request using Postman or do you still get a 400 error?

Comment: Yes it is working perfectly on post man.. anyways it worked now, there was two issues first one you solve the typo one. Second i was edcoding the body before sending and when i removed it start working. Thank you so much for your help.